# SQL Query to find exclusive customer

Tags: mysql, sql

I have a table with two columns Cust and Category,

```
**Cust   Category**

   1         X
   2         Y
   1         Y
   2         Z
   3         X
   4         D
```

Customer 1 has purchased from category X and Y, but for 'Category X', 3 is an exclusive customer since Cust 3 purchased only from X. I want a result like below with three columns (Category, No of Customer purchased in the category and Exclusive Customer):

```
**Category  NoOfCust  ExclusiveCust**

    X         2              3
    Y         2             NULL
    Z         1             NULL
    D         1              4
```

How can I query the table to get this result?

Comment: Stackoverflow, is not a free coding service

Comment: Please show what you have tried so that we can help you out.

Comment: Hi all....I tried with the below Query but it throwing an error..
select category,count(cust) as NoofCust,(select (cust) from sales group by cust having count(category)=1)
from sales group by Category

Answer (score 0):

Used a temp table to duplicate your structure:

```
SELECT 
    Category, 
    COUNT(*) as NoOfCust, 
    CASE WHEN COUNT(*) = 1 THEN MAX(ID_W) ELSE NULL END as Exclusive
FROM #WORKER T
GROUP BY Category
```

Comment: Hi..thanks for the suggestion but am not getting a right output..When i execute a above query am getting an output as below..

Category NoOfCust  Exclusive
D 1 4
X 2 NULL
Y 2 NULL
Z 1 2